# What is the best way to turn on 12V light at specific time for 5 minutes?

Tags: relay, timer, trigger

I have 12V/3A power supply which is supplying 12V light. I need to turn on light at 6am, 14pm and 20pm for 5 minutes. What is the best way to do that?

I was thinking about RTC module which has it's own time battery but I didn't find way to program that to turn on at specific time. I also searched for 555 timer circuits but it isn't used for long delays like mine.

Comment: Easiest : programmable (or mechanical) mains timer turning the PSU on/off.

Comment: I can't turn PSU on/off because everything must be supplied with that PSU.

Comment: "Best" is a pretty nebulous specification. Do  you care what happens in the case of a power failure and time is lost (the infamous blinking 12:00 syndrome?). What if it loses time slowly? For some applications a Raspberry Pi with backup UPS and NTP time synchronization might be pretty good, for others a motor-based mechanical timer would be perfect.

Comment: if 20:00 was changed ro 22:00 it would be easy to solve using a cheap timer. 5 minutes on then 475 minutes off repeating.

Comment: "DIN Rail Clock 12V" yields a lot of results with my favourite search engine.

Comment: I'd write software for a micro-controller with RTC function.  It is going to be difficult to get the accuracy otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that a 555 is not the way to solve this problem. To do this with a microcontroller you need one with that has or interfaces with a real-time clock, some programming (and date and time programs are generally tricky) and some additional hardware to switch the light.

- If you want to learn then you could look around at various developer systems such as Arduino, etc.
- If you want to solve a problem in a way that someone else can modify it then buy a commercial timer. This can switch the mains input to the 12 V power supply. Costs are as low as < €10, £8, US$12 but watch out for quality.

[image]

*Figure 1. A programmable plug-in timer. Image source: Amazon.com.*

Comment: If it's to control 12V only, then this can still be used. Just switch an AC relay contact with the output?

Comment: @NatsuKage Yes, that will solve my problem i think. Thank you.